# SQL Pivot Strings / Multiple Unpivoted Columns

Tags: sql, database, teradata

New to SQL and would like some help "pivoting" a table. Here's what I'm trying to do...

Oracle Database Format:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Sale Start  ║ Sale End ║   Store   ║ Promotion ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1/1         ║ 4/1      ║ Nike      ║ 10% OFF   ║
║ 1/1         ║ 4/1      ║ Adidas    ║ 20% OFF   ║
║ 1/1         ║ 6/1      ║ Reebok    ║ 30% OFF   ║
║ 2/1         ║ 4/1      ║ Nike      ║ 40% OFF   ║
║ 2/1         ║ 4/1      ║ Reebok    ║ 50% OFF   ║
║ 3/1         ║ 4/1      ║ Adidas    ║ 60% OFF   ║
║ 3/1         ║ 4/1      ║ Sketchers ║ 70% OFF   ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Desired Output:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Sale Start  ║ Sale End ║  Nike   ║ Adidas  ║ Reebok  ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 1/1         ║ 4/1      ║ 10% OFF ║ 20% OFF ║         ║
║ 1/1         ║ 6/1      ║         ║         ║ 30% OFF ║
║ 2/1         ║ 4/1      ║ 40% OFF ║         ║ 50% OFF ║
║ 3/1         ║ 4/1      ║         ║ 60% OFF ║         ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

To answer potential questions:

- The output should only list the UNIQUE sale date periods.
- I don't want to pivot all stores, e.g. I don't need to pull Sketchers' rows.

New to Stack Overflow so please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you need to pull Sketchers' rows?is there any logic or just special for Sketchers?

Comment: @D-Shih The actual data table has 100 or so Stores. I didn't want the output table to be 100 columns wide. I only cared about a few relevant stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a standard pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    [Sale Start],
    [Sale End],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Store = 'Nike'   THEN Promotion END) AS Nike,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Store = 'Adidas' THEN Promotion END) AS Adidas,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Store = 'Reebok' THEN Promotion END) AS Reebok
FROM yourTable
WHERE Store IN ('Nike', 'Adidas', 'Reebok')
GROUP BY
    [Sale Start],
    [Sale End];
```

The requirement to not include Sketchers data is met by just not having a term in the select clause to pivot that data.

Note that you did not tell us which database you are using.  I have assumed SQL Server, where column names with spaces can be escaped using square brackets.  In other databases, you would need to escape in other ways.